# Can we sync Employeeid on prem AD property to Azure Ad using Ad Connect?

Tags: active-directory, azure, entra-id

We want to sync ad property employeeid stored in our on prem ad to azure ad. We used AD connect sync completed sucessfully, but we dont see those properties tagged into users hosted in AZure Ad.

Am i doing something wrong or does microsoft has something going on against that field?

Answer (score 2):

The employeeID Attribute is not one that is synchronized by default by the Azure AD Connect application, as detailed in this link (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/connect/active-directory-aadconnectsync-attributes-synchronized).

However, by following the instructions in this link (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/connect/active-directory-aadconnect-get-started-custom#directory-extension-attribute-sync) under the section titled Directory Extension Attribute Sync, you should be able to extend the Azure AD schema and include the employeeID attribute in the sync process.